# does rosbag guarantee data will be published correctly everytime?

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assume i have a bag file and run it multiple times. In those times, is the data the same ? ( i mean is there any data lost?)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224675/does-rosbag-guarantee-data-will-be-published-correctly-everytime-?/) by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2016-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No. rosbag may skip messages during playback to maintain the desired playback speed. If rosbag starts playing messages immediately, the first message or two may be missed by the subscriber, before the topic is set up.

You can use the `-d` option to have rosbag delay between advertising a topic and starting playback, to give subscribers time to connect.

You can slow down the publish rate with the `-r` option, and this can help prevent dropped message; this works particularly well when used with the `--clock` option and the `use_sim_time` parameter.

Have a look at the [rosbag command line](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#play) page for more interesting options that you can use with rosbag.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As described by @ahendrix, data apparently could be dropped if the desired playback time would otherwise not be reached. Two further potential caveats:

- There will be some jitter/small differences in the
  publishing and arrival time of data
  at subscribers due to system CPU load and other random factors
- If data is published at very high
  rates, it might exceed queue sizes,
  in which case some data could be
  dropped. This is true for both the
  publisher (i.e. `rosbag play`) and
  subscriber sides. For both, the queue size has to be set appropriately (See queue related params for [rosbag (play)](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#play) and [for subscribers](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Subscriber_Options).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-01-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2016-01-21**:
i can see the queue size of the rosbag and subscriber node affect the result of my algorithm which is not desirable. Thanks for your help

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2016-01-21**:
i have 1 more question. when i filter one topic out of the bag into another bag and run the same nodes to process that topic. Everytime i run the new bag file, it gives me slightly different results . Why that happened?